# Adding VBA code to ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, installation, vba

I have a VBA code and I need to add it to ARCMap 10.2.2 but not sure how to do it I couldn't find anything online.

Comment: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/arcgis-desktop/10.2/index.html#//008700000012000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the same answer that @mkennedy wrote as a comment by using Google to search on "arcgis 10.2 vba".

The first result was a page entitled [Installing ArcGIS for Desktop VBA Compatibility](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/arcgis-desktop/10.2/index.html#//008700000012000000):

> At ArcGIS 10.2.1 and 10.2.2, the VBA runtime is installed by the
>   setup.exe of the ArcGIS VBA Compatibility setup program. Previous to
>   ArcGIS 10, the VBA Runtime was installed by the ArcGIS for Desktop
>   setup.
>
> To run the ArcGIS VBA Compatibility setup, use the setup.exe located
>   in the \ArcGIS_VBA folder on the installation media or download
>   folder, or select the ArcGIS for Desktop VBA Compatibility link on the
>   ArcGIS for Desktop startup menu.
>
> After installing ArcGIS for Desktop VBA Compatibility, you must obtain
>   an authorization file for VBA.

Also note:

> The VBA setup is not an upgrade setup. If you have the VBA setup from
>   10.2.1 installed, that VBA installation is compatible with ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop and can remain.

I recommend reviewing the Online Help page linked to above because the quotes above are just short excerpts from more comprehensive documentation.

Comment: VBA is being deprecated. There were warnings that as of 10.2 Esri wasn't going to allow it but it ended up being in the install although not easy to find. I suggest that anyone with VBA code get Visual Studio 2010 (Express - free and works but not in a commercial environment) and create an add-in.. after initial setup you can copy and paste forms/code from VBA... If I remember correctly the 'set' commands are removed automatically, if not find & replace 'set' with ''.